# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"

Tags: 7

I've some db_query that I change to drupal 7 API use db_select but Iam received error like this

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at
>   or near "FROM" LINE 2: FROM ^: SELECT FROM {jurnal_kas} jurnal_kas
>   WHERE (id = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 42387 )

db_query();

```
$jkas = db_query("SELECT * FROM {jurnal_kas} WHERE id=$id")->fetchAssoc();
```

db_select();

```
$jkas = db_select('jurnal_kas')   ->condition('id', $id)  
->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

Can anyone help that will be great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't selecting any field, (See [Dynamic queries: fields](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/fields).)

For example, you could select all fields with code similar to the following.

```
$jkas = db_select('jurnal_kas')
  ->fields('jurnal_kas')
  ->condition('id', $id)  
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();
```